# how to get raw events from Firebase analytics using api without BigQuery?

Tags: python, firebase, api, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I need to extract raw events from Firebase Analytics using python SDK. Actually, we can link a BigQuery to a firebase and access raw events through BigQuery. But it is not clear from the documentation is there any other ways to extract events without BigQuery?

Comment: Sonnh, are you looking for any other information.

Comment: Yes @VaidehiJamankar. i looking for data like when use option sync to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/trusted-testing/analytics-data) that you can use to run Analytics reports and retrieve data.
The Google Analytics Data API gives programmatic access to users by country.
In Data API requests, you'll need to identify your Google Analytics 4 (GA4) property by its ID; this ID is different from the Firebase project. There are client libraries in Java, [Python](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py), Node.js, and other languages to simplify your implementation.

Comment: i know It only exposes aggregate information not raw data

Comment: This Analytics Data API seems to be the option at the moment .Also you may look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=web which describes details around this.

Answer (score 0):

You could download CSV file of your Analytics reports. Though, Google Analytics exports only up to 5k rows when you download a report as a CSV.

To export a report:

1. Click  in the top right of most reports.
2. Click Download File.
3. Select an option:

- Export to Google Sheets
- Download CSV

You could check [this](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7521152?hl=en) for your reference.